# How to use lightbox inline HTML function in drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal, lightbox

I have successfully installed lightbox module in drupal and now using it for 'sign in' page. It is working fine. Now i want to use it for 'Inline HTML' but i don't know how to do that. Please help me out.

I'm using the following code:

```
<p><a rel="lightmodal" href="#example">Test</a></p>
<div style="display: none">
<div id="example">Hello</div>
</div>
```

But this code is showing the entire page in the lightbox whereas i just to see "Hello" inside the lightbox.

Please help me out.

Comment: Try to be more specific and explain the problem in greater detail.

Comment: Well to be very specific. I have a textarea like this 

<textbox name="text" cols="50" rows=50"> Text here </textarea>
<input type = "button" name="test" value="check">

When i press this button i want to the see the contents of textarea in the dialogue box using lightbox effect. It should display contents in the pop up or diaglogue box using lightbox module.

If this is clear please let me know the exact code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use rel="lightbox", not lightmodal.  Try that.

Comment: I have just tried it but it gives blank pop up using lightbox. Nothing appears in it.
Any other suggestion.
It was recommened to use "lightmodal" to use inline html.

Comment: Lightbox doesn't seem to work with div tags and anchors.  can you put the content in a seperate page?  You can then just link to the page instead using lightmodal.

Comment: Well to be very specific. I have a textarea like this <textbox name="text" cols="50" rows=50"> Text here </textarea> <input type = "button" name="test" value="check"> When i press this button i want to the see the contents of textarea in the dialogue box using lightbox effect. It should display contents in the pop up or diaglogue box using lightbox module. If this is clear please let me know the exact code. Thanks.